# How to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database in Android?

Tags: java, android

I develop simple application in android. Its execute successfully but some time its stopped unfortunately and throw error like these

A `SQLiteConnection` object for database `'/data/data/com.h2o/databases/MyDBName.db'` was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

What i do to avoid above error

Here my db code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String ADDRESS_TABLE_NAME = "address";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_ADDRESSTYPE = "addrtype";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_LINE1 = "line1";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_LINE2 = "line2";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_CITY = "city";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_ZIPCODE = "zipcode";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_STATE = "state";
    public static final String ADDRESS_COLUMN_LANDMARK = "landmark";



    //private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table address " +
                        "(id integer primary key autoincrement,addrtype text not null unique, line1 text not null,line2 text not null,city text not null,zipcode text not null, country textnot null,state text not null,landmark text)"
        );



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS address");

        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertAddress(String addrtype, String line1, String line2, String city, String zipcode, String country, String state, String landmark)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db;

        db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("addrtype", addrtype);
        contentValues.put("line1", line1);
        contentValues.put("line2", line2);
        contentValues.put("city", city);
        contentValues.put("zipcode", zipcode);
        contentValues.put("country", country);
        contentValues.put("state", state);
        contentValues.put("landmark", landmark);

        String selectQuery = "select * from address where addrtype ='"+addrtype+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        if (cursor.getCount()==1){

            db.update("address",contentValues,"addrtype ='"+addrtype+"'",null);
            return true;
        }
        else {

            db.insert("address", null, contentValues);
            return true;
        }

    }


    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from address where id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, ADDRESS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }

    public boolean updateAddress (Integer id,String addrtype, String line1, String line2, String city, String zipcode,String country,String state,String landmark)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("addrtype", addrtype);
        contentValues.put("line1", line1);
        contentValues.put("line2", line2);
        contentValues.put("city", city);
        contentValues.put("zipcode", zipcode);
        contentValues.put("country", country);
        contentValues.put("state", state);
        contentValues.put("landmark", landmark);
        db.update("address", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteAddress (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("address",
                "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllAddress()
    {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from address", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ADDRESS_COLUMN_ADDRESSTYPE)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }



}
```

AddressFragment.java:

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this.getActivity());

Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;

                rs.moveToFirst();
                String addr_type = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_ADDRESSTYPE));
                String addr_line1 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_LINE1));
                String addr_line2 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_LINE2));
                String addr_city = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_CITY));
                String addr_zipcode = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_ZIPCODE));
                addr_country_index = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_COUNTRY));
                addr_state_index = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_STATE));
                String addr_landmark = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_LANDMARK));

                if (!rs.isClosed())
                {
                    rs.close();
                    mydb.close();
                }
```

Please anyone fix it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your full stack trace

Comment: full stack trace means?

Comment: It is important to know during which flow or operation this problem occurs. You have multiple methods for db interaction. Your logcat usually shows stack trace of method calls that occurred just before your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because you are not closing 'Cursor' object.
 Each Cursor should be closed when you're finished with it. The safe way to do this is:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from address", null);
    try {
        // read data from the cursor in here
    } finally {
        res.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this way:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        //myDb is Database Helper Class
        if(myDb.getReadableDatabase().isOpen())myDb.getReadableDatabase().close();
        if(myDb.getWritableDatabase().isOpen())myDb.getWritableDatabase().close();
    }
```